# NSArray count returns correct number but faults with data access

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I am attempting to get a count of items in an array to place it in the `right detail` of a `cell`. Interestingly enough I am getting the proper `count` but my when I try to `NSLog` the array it returns `<fault>`.

```
NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"muscleGroup == %@ && specificExercise == %@ && date >= %@ && date < %@", theMuscleGroup, theExercise, fromDate, toDate];

NSFetchRequest *fetchRequestTemp = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription
                               entityForName:@"WeightLiftingInfo" inManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext];

[fetchRequestTemp setPredicate:searchPredicate];
[fetchRequestTemp setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;
NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:[_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestTemp error:&error]];

NSLog(@"%@", tempArray);
NSLog(@"%d", [tempArray count]);
```

**My Question:**
Basically, what am I doing wrong? Am i initing the array improperly or trying to log it improperly?

I have been researching for hours and trying different coding, but cannot figure it out. Any help would be appreciated. **If you need more info or I am doing something against guidelines according to SO please let me know before you close this thread or "-1". HAVE MERCY, I am new and leaning:)**

Comment: It may be that the array objects are on a different threads. Core Data does not support multithreading "out of the box." Are you using multithreading? Are you having trouble actually using the results instead of logging them?

Comment: @ilias I have not been trying to use them as I figured it would fault when accessed. See my response to caleb below as I explain a little bit more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you execute your fetch request, you get back a [managed object fault](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdFaultingUniquing.html). That is, a proxy-like object that represents the results even though the real data objects haven't been loaded from the data store yet. The fault knows how many objects are in the array, etc., and when you access the objects the fault will transparently load the real objects.

So, situation normal, don't worry about it. Try *using* the results instead of logging them and I think you'll find that things work fine.

Comment: Thanks! I actually just need the count so I have not been using the results. I wasn't sure if I needed to worry about this `<fault>`.

Comment: No problem. One of the things that makes Core Data fast is that it defers loading the data until you really need it. BTW, I doubt that you need the whole `initWithArray:` bit... just use the array that you get back from executing the fetch.

Comment: Is this what you mean? `NSArray *tempArray = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequestTemp error:&error];`? If so, what is the difference?

Comment: Right -- you've got it. The MOC hands you an array, so no need to create another one especially since you just need the count.